# How do I replace an ImageView with a Layout containing many elements in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an ImageView which among other elements is contained in a main linear layout. On a certain button click , I want to replace the ImageView with a Linear Layout. Is there a way to do this in Android ? I already set up the event listener and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add other Linear Layout in your ImageView's parent with

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then on your event handler you can just set visibility gone for the image view and visible to the LinearLayout.

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the ImageView's visibility to View.GONE and the LinearLayout's visibility to View.VISIBLE in the button's OnClickListener.

Put the LinearLayout after the ImageView in the parent LinearLayout, and set its visibility to "gone" in the xml file.